# Redirect URL having symbol of # after trailing slash in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have my site in WordPress.

I have seen one URL of my site in Google Search results like below:

```
http://homeurl/#!info/citr
```

The above URL creates duplicate link of my home page.

So I want to build a code to 301 redirect URL containing symbol `#` after trailing slash of home URL to home page like below:

```
http://homeurl/#
```

Should redirect to home page URL.

Can anybody help me to build such code?

Comment: please someone reply...

Comment: Look into Google canonical URLs: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en